# "He'amur" rather than "ha'amur" in K'dusha introduction?

Tags: pronunciation, chazzan-prayer-leader, kedusha-prayer

A *shali'ach tzibur* I heard recently, in the [introductory paragraph of *K'dusha*](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%94_%28%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%29#.D7.94.D7.A7.D7.93.D7.9E.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.9C.22.D7.A7.D7.93.D7.95.D7.A9.22) on *shabas* morning read the line "kadavar **he**'amur al yad n'vi'echa". A fellow audience member said that he does this deliberately, claiming the pronunciation "he'amur" rather than "ha'amur" is the way Shlomo Carlebach did it (and the correct way, whatever that means). Is there a basis for this pronunciation in known *k'dusha* texts?

Comment: Just to clarify: "he" means ה with a segol, and "ha" means ה with a kamatz?

Comment: http://dikdukian.weeklyshtikle.com/2013/09/songs-that-get-it-wrong.html?showComment=1379444513116#c4009500947841699213

Comment: @DoubleAA People speak with sounds, not dots. I would transcribe it something like [hɛʔʌmʊɹ].

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but normally _heamur_ would mean "that's heaped" whereas _haamur_ means "that's said".

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the quality of stop in between the "e" and "a"?

Comment: Was that addressed to me, WAF? Most _Ashk'nazim_ don't distinguish between an א, an ע, and ∅ in actual pronunciation, though they keep the vowels that the books indicate: thus _haamur_ would be with an א whereas _heamur_ would be with an ע.